# VNC connection over SSH Tunnel with "middleman" server (Windows Viewer to Mac Server)

Tags: ssh, vnc, putty, ssh-tunnel, tightvnc

I NEED HELP!

So I have a windows 8 PC (vnc viewer) and a iMac 10.8 Mountain Lion (vnc server) and a middleman server running ubuntu on a DMZ (all ports open). Both computers are behind a firewall with NO PORTS OPEN to the external world (except the middleman server).

VNC Server (iMac): phil@192.168.1.106 (Private IP)
Username: phil

Middleman Server: fixnode@fixnode.ca (I use domain names instead of IP for simplicity)
Username: fixnode

VNC Viewer (Windows 8 PC): 24.114.25.11 (private IP) 
(No SSH Server on PC)

**Step 1:** From the VNC Server (iMac) I run this command: `ssh -f -N -R 5900:localhost:5900 fixnode@fixnode.ca` and then I turn on my VNC server.

**Step 2:** Then from the Viewer (Windows 8 PC) I run Putty (ssh client) to connect to `fixnode@fixnode.ca -p 5900`

Note: In putty there is no feedback so I assume the tunnel is created (since there is no error)

**Step 3:** Using TightVNC Viewer (On Windows 8 PC) I put `localhost:5900` and click connect

When I try to connect the viewer to the iMac the error I get is a timeout error, I have tried to edit my sshd_config file (on the middleman server) to allow gateway connections but nothing helps. Can anyone give me any suggestions?

Just to clarify BOTH PC and Mac are behind a firewall with NO PORTS OPEN

Thanks,
Phillip K

Comment: Anybody have an answer?

Comment: I'm working on a similar problem: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82386/remote-desktop-over-ssh-reverse-tunnel-to-replace-teamviewer

Comment: Basically, you are telling the "server" to listen on 127.0.0.1 on the middleman server and telling the "client" to connect to a different address on the middleman server.  You need to change the -R argument to either -R <IP address of fixnode.ca>:5900:localhost:5900 -or- -R *:5900:localhost:5900.  This change requires that the SSHD server have GatewayPorts enabled.